# Not picking up where clause - sorted Procedure MySql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

**Table** : `ID, UserID, NumberOfHours, WeekCommencing`

The procedure add in a new row for each user, when there are 12 row for any one user it is required to delete the earliest row against that user and add a new row. Else just add a row.
This Keep a running record of the last 12 weeks hours for each user.

**PROBLEM** the "`select count`" does not pick up the where clause for some reason?

```
    CREATE DEFINER PROCEDURE `Avghours`(IN `Userid` INT, IN `Hours` DECIMAL(5,2), IN `WCdate` DATE)

    BEGIN
    DECLARE NUM INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM avghours
    WHERE UserID = Userid
    INTO NUM;

    IF NUM >= 12 then
    DELETE FROM avghours WHERE UserID = Userid
    ORDER BY UserID LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO avghours(
    UserID
   ,NumberOfHours
    ,WeekCommencing)
    VALUES(
    Userid
   ,Hours
   ,WCdate);

   END
```

Comment: Try do define `userID` variable with name different than column name in `avghours`. Now both are the same (no matter case sensitivity)

Comment: Already try it, made no difference

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO NUM FROM... WHERE...` - i.e. move `into` clause right after `count` function.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this you will get the point

```
   mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_testyt`()
    -> BEGIN
    -> 
    -> DECLARE NUMM INT;
    -> SELECT count(*) FROM gg into NUMM;
    -> SELECT @NUMM;
    -> 
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> call sp_testyt();
+-------+
| @NUMM |
+-------+
| NULL  |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

----------- corrected SP ------------

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_testtt`()
    -> BEGIN
    -> DECLARE NUM INT;
    -> SELECT count(*) FROM gg into @NUM;
    -> SELECT @NUM;
    -> 
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> CALL sp_testtt();
+------+
| @NUM |
+------+
|    4 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Update your delete query

```
DELETE FROM avghours WHERE ID in (SELECT ID FROM avghours WHERE Userid=Userid ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: initialize  your variable and then use it

Comment: Can not see were your going with this one, setting num to 0 make no difference in the procedure.

Comment: that has sorted out the count problem but the procedure is still failing 
    DELETE FROM avghours WHERE UserID = Userid
    ORDER BY UserID LIMIT 1;
The where clause is not picking up the User and just deleting the earliest row regardless of user.

Comment: PLEASE UPDATE your delete query

Comment: Version of Mysql in use does not accept subquery with Stored Procedure, but thanks for trying.